# Suse 11.4 no volume group found

Tags: lvm, partition, boot, vmware-player, sles11

I'm using suse 11.4 on a vmwareplayer 15.
I had an issue of / been 100% full and also didn't reboot the machine for a long time.
After I cleaned some space I rebooted the machine and now I get these errors :

```
FATAL MODE incomplete logical volumes will be processed
Volume group "vg-root" not found

mount: devpts already mounted or /dev/pts is busy
FATAL: Module linear not found
FATAL: Module dm_mirror not found
Volume group "vg-root" not found
```

After i booted to single mode 
I tried this:

```
cat /etc/fstab - not found
cat /dev/mapper/ - only file there is control
chroot - not found
vgchange -ay - no volume group found 
fsck - cant find anything to fix.
mount- shows only tmpfs
```

It's like all vg's and lv's are gone. (vgscan lvscan pvscan not finding anything)
What else can I do?

Comment: What exactly did you do to "clean some space"?

Comment: delete /tmp/ file

Comment: I mean /tmp/ file enteris. i think that its because we didnt reboot the machine
For long time and it had an issue, and the reboot triggerd it.

Answer (score 1):

When a system will not boot, rescue it from another environment. Boot rescue media, or boot a different VM and attach a copy of their disks. Copy off important data. Optionally, attempt to fix LVM.

Or, build a new host and restore from backups.

Comment: can your share some link maybe with step by step guide ?

Comment: No, because I don't know what is wrong with your LVM. Boot a working OS and try to mount the volumes with your data.